# Wiremock Integration Issue with Scalatest

Tags: scala, scalatest, wiremock

I am having trouble integrating Wiremock with a Scalatest specification. I am using this version of Wiremock:

```
"com.github.tomakehurst"  %  "wiremock-jre8"       % "2.22.0"    % "test",
```

I created a `WiremockSpec` looks like this:

```
trait WiremockSpec extends BeforeAndAfterAll { self: Suite =>

  import WireMockConfiguration._

  protected val wiremockServer = new WireMockServer(options().dynamicPort())

  override protected def beforeAll(): Unit = {
    super.beforeAll()
    wiremockServer.start()
  }

  override protected def afterAll(): Unit = {
    wiremockServer.stop()
    super.afterAll()
  }

  // some helper methods

}
```

And then mix it into my specification as follows:

```
class MySpec() extends PlaySpec with Matchers with MockitoSugar with GuiceOneAppPerSuite
with ScalaFutures with WiremockSpec with IntegrationPatience
```

When I run the test, I get this error:

```
An exception or error caused a run to abort: Not listening on HTTP port. The WireMock server is most likely stopped 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not listening on HTTP port. The WireMock server is most likely stopped
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:507)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.WireMockServer.port(WireMockServer.java:178)
    at MySpec.<init>(MySpec.scala:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.genSuiteConfig(Runner.scala:1428)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.$anonfun$doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun$8(Runner.scala:1236)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:286)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun(Runner.scala:1235)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$24(Runner.scala:1031)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$24$adapted(Runner.scala:1010)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.withClassLoaderAndDispatchReporter(Runner.scala:1506)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter(Runner.scala:1010)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.run(Runner.scala:850)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner.run(Runner.scala)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner.runScalaTest2(ScalaTestRunner.java:131)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner.main(ScalaTestRunner.java:28)
```

I tried [this](https://github.com/tomakehurst/wiremock/issues/369) solution but I still get the same error. Anybody know why this is happening? I am suspecting it maybe down to the way the trait is being initialised?

Comment: It is definitely a trait ordering issue. I took out the WiremockSpec mixin and explicitly put the Wiremock setup code inside the actual scalatest specification and it works fine. This is most likely a Scalatest issue and the way it initialises certain of its traits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally tracked this down to the `PlaySpec` trait. Swapping this out with `FlatSpec` avoids the clash with the wiremock server start up. Same with `WordSpec`, it also clashes. `FlatSpec` works fine. I still need to dig into why this happens.